# Visual Studio 2022 adding extra tabs on format for Javascript multiple line template literal

Tags: javascript, razor, visual-studio-2022, template-literals

Does anyone know how to make Ctrl+K Ctrl+D (format document) stop adding additional tabs every time you format the document?

I have a multiple line template literal. In Visual Studio 2022, every time I press Ctrl+K Ctrl+D to format the .cshtml document, all multi line template literals are tabbed over once. (see picture)

[image]

I've searched all over and find nothing.  Most searches want to talk about VSCode.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.4

Comment: I have the same issue with C# and sadly haven't got to the bottom of it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looked at this again and noticed the .editorconfig file had:

```
tab_width = 2
indent_size = 4
```

But my tab settings in VS were 2 and 2.  VS evidently was getting confused between the two and *having a moment*.  I changed the indent_size to 2, and restarted VS and it's been better since.